# How to discover a mobx observer's properties in a browser's dev console?

Tags: typescript, mobx-react

In the project I am working dependency injection is used very extensively.

There are code like this

```
type BigWidget = {
   title: string,
}


const AProps = {
  b: BigWidget
}

class A extends React.Component<AProps> {
  ...
}

...
const a = <A b={observerB} />
```

The problem with prop `b` above is that it could be created in many ways

```
import * as mobxReact from 'mobx-react';
const observerB = mboxReact.observer( { title }: { title: string } ) => {...}
```

or

```
const anotherObserverB = mboxReact.observer( { title, extraFunction }:
    { title: string, extraFunction:() => void } ) => {...}
```

I want to be able to identify what object has been passed to prop `b`. Is there an easy to tell, for example, the observer has a prop `extraFunction` or not in dev console?

Currently if I type `a` in the console, it is all I can see

[image]

and it is not very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified code that will compile:

```
export type AProps = {
  b: any
}

export class A extends React.Component<AProps> {
  render() {
    return <div />
  }
}

const observerB = observer(() => { return <div /> });

const a = <A b={observerB} />
```

Now you want to know what is the value of `b` passed to a. Its available under props:

```
console.log(a.props['b'] === observerB); // True
```

## Full code

```
export type AProps = {
  b: any
}

export class A extends React.Component<AProps> {
  render() {
    return <div />
  }
}

const observerB = observer(() => { return <div /> });

const a = <A b={observerB} />
console.log(a); // What you have 
console.log(a.props['b'] === observerB); // True
```